# Can a bathroom and adjacent wetbar use the same 20amp circuit for receptacles only

Tags: electrical, bathroom, gfci

Our homebuilders have 1 hall bath receptacles and 1 master bathroom receptacles plus 2 shower lights using 2 independent gfci runs (1 for each bathroom) on one 20amp circuit.

Can I do the same in our basement with a gfci feeding 3 outlets and 2 shower lights in the bathroom and one gfci feeding 2 outlets in an adjacent walk up bar or is this only allowed with bathrooms?

We will have other bathroom lighting on a 15amp circuit should the shower lights trip, and all appliances in adjacent bar will be on a separate circuit.

Comment: You can have as many GFCI as you wish, some are must have

Comment: Depending on when the house was built, you may have existing wiring that was OK *at the time built* and is grandfathered. If so, you don't have to bring it up to current code, but you can't make it worse - e.g., if a circuit is shared between bathroom and non-bathroom, I am pretty sure you can't add additional non-bathroom receptacles. But you can't replicate the same type of wiring in a new circuit - a new circuit needs to be bathroom dedicated if it has any bathroom receptacles.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean "can I have all these things on one circuit":

No, you may not do that. Required countertop receptacles in one bathroom may share a circuit with either: countertop receptacles in other bathrooms or lighting in the same bathroom (not both). NEC 210.11 (C) 3.

(NEC 2020 further restricted things such that if one circuit serves bathroom countertop circuits in more than one bathroom the circuit may not serve non-countertop bathroom outlets (bidets, etc) but that doesn't affect you either way.)

“Wet bar” receptacles are not bathroom receptacles or bathroom lighting, so no. They’ll have to be on a different circuit.